# How to change the "page not found" page in a server

Tags: server

How do you change the default page that says "this page is not found on this server"?

Where is it located so i can change it? Because i want to change if for my own.

Its the 404 error ("page not found"), like this is a example of a server pages not found

- http://www.apple.com/apple/
- http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/hosting/error_message_displayed_by_web_server_for_non_existent_page.gif

Just to be clear the page is not their i just want to change the page that is shown if that page is not found on that server.

Comment: is that better ...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663459/custom-404-page-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to your [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

where 404.html is the name of your html document which will show when handling 404 error.